# Regular expression group. Extract as few parameters in one group

Tags: php, regex

I have string `some-other/other/ram/1gb/2gb/other`, and want to parse `ram` group, which must capture repeatable parameters. (it's for url filtration `ram/1gb/2gb/4gb`, means group `ram` and captured values array(`1gb`, `2gb`, `4gb`) )

What I must change in my regular expression to capture array of parameters under one parameter group?
Now I have:

```
$str = "some-other/other/ram/1gb/2gb/other";
$possible_values = implode('|', array('1gb','2gb','4gb','8gb','12gb','16gb','32gb'))
$compiled = "#(.*)ram/(?P<ram>{$possible_values})(.*)$#uD";

if(preg_match($compiled,$str,$matches){
var_dump($matches['ram'])
//output is string '1gb', but I want to see array('1gb', '2gb')
}
```

what must I change? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$compiled = "#^(.*)ram/(?P<ram>(?:{$possible_values}/?)+)(/(?:.*))$#uD";
```

The inner group matches any sequence of the possible values, separated `/`.

`preg_match` won't return an array for a repetition operator. Use `explode('/', $matches['ram'])` to split it up.

Comment: You seem to be missing the ending parenthesis, right before `$`

Comment: You said : "preg_match won't return an array for a repetition operator", so your proposition turns me in the right way to do few manipulation and get the result what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is probably easier than you think, here's my 5 cents:

```
$ram = "some-other/other/ram/1gb/2gb/other";
if (preg_match('%/ram/%i', $ram)) {
    preg_match_all('/(\d+gb)/i', $ram, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
}
 var_dump($matches[1]);
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "1gb"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "2gb"
}
```

**DEMO:**

http://ideone.com/jMoobu

Comment: This doesn't look for them specifically after `/ram/`.

Comment: I understand your logic. But this solution is not so universal as I want. I'm in developing "REST like" parametrical query string parser. Which must parse 3 formats: single, multi and range formats. 
single example $key/$value
multi example $key/$value1/$value2/$value3/...
range example $key/$minValue/to/$maxValue

And $value regular expression must be set according to the rules of php framework what i'm working with.